# SELECT INTO #temp.. FROM [Query1] OR [Query2]

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

**Added clarification**: My code is run inside a Stored Procedure.

I've run into this issue multiple times over the years so thought I'd bite the bullet and finally ask, even though I think I might be missing a simple solution.

Oftentimes is the case I like to use

```
SELECT * INTO #Temp FROM ...
```

.. Because I find it generally performs better than any other means of temp table generation when used on small data sets.

But sometimes I'll have a parameterised query which can run in more than one "mode", thus need my statement to be able to populate #Temp from two completely different sources depending on this mode, e.g.

Option 1

```
IF @RoleID > -1
    SELECT PrivilegeID INTO dbo.#Privs FROM Users.tblRolePrivilegeLink WHERE RoleID = @RoleID
```

Option 2

```
    IF @UserID > -1 
        SELECT PrivilegeID INTO dbo.#Privs FROM dbo.fn_UserPrivileges(@UserID)
```

In this example I'm trying to get a set of privileges for either a role or a user, one straight from a table, another from a function.

I know I could use the regular INSERT INTO.. logic but I'd be really interested to see if there's an actual solution for doing it this way. Maybe with CTE's or somesuch.

**Solution**

```
-- Get distinct privileges
SELECT  PrivilegeID
INTO    dbo.#Privs 
FROM
(
        SELECT PrivilegeID FROM Users.tblRolePrivilegeLink WHERE RoleID > -1 AND RoleID = @RoleID
        UNION
        SELECT PrivilegeID FROM dbo.fn_UserPrivileges(@UserID) WHERE @UserID > -1
) AS T
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
INTO dbo.#Privs 
from (
  SELECT PrivilegeID 
  FROM   Users.tblRolePrivilegeLink 
  WHERE  RoleID = @RoleID and @RoleID > -1

  UNION

  SELECT PrivilegeID 
  FROM   dbo.fn_UserPrivileges(@UserID)
  WHERE  @UserID  > 1)
```

Comment: If you try to compile that it'll error, it doesn't let you select into the same table twice.

Comment: Yeah that works, thanks. Seems simple actually, a case of can't see woods for the trees methinks. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do thisby separating the staetments using "go":

```
if 1=0 select 1 as v into #temp;
go
if 1=1 select 2 as v into #temp;
go
select * from #temp
```

This code assumes that `#temp` does not exist initially.

Comment: @JanineRawnsley . . . No you cannot.  I didn't see that as a requirement in the question.

Comment: Yeah sorry, sometimes I forget not everyone uses SPs ;-)